# C++ Reading and Writing 2 text files simultaneously

Tags: c++, text

I'm able to write to a text file and read from a textfile, but I can't save what I've read and handle it if I read another file!

```
ifstream in;
ofstream out;

in.open("text.in", fstream::in);
if (!in.is_open()) return -1;

out.open("text.out", fstream::out);
if (!out.is_open()) return -1;
string line;

getline(in, line);

cout << line << endl;

in.close();
out.close();

return 0;
```

Normally the above prints out the first line from the "text.in" file, but if I open the "text.out" file it doesn't work!

How can I open two text files at the same time?

Thank you!

Comment: Oh I made a mockup of the problem, I thought I'd be lazy and do both the opening and checking on the same line - I'll clean it up. But the question remains unanswered.

Comment: The code as posted is fine. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: The code you have works just fine. It doesn't save anything to text.out but that's as you've coded it.

Comment: You're not writing to 'out' anywhere.  Did you intend to be?

Comment: Thanks for confirming the code. I've been slamming my head against the desk trying to use stringstreams and in.rdbuf() and all sorts of things. The bug was in my Command Line arguments handling function. Specifically this line: `if (argc <= 2) in.open() ... if( argc > 2) out.open()`. So whenever I added an output file as a command line argument it skipped over opening the in file. ._.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are printing to `cout` not the `out` file.

```
cout << line << endl;


// Add (or replace) the above line

out << line << endl;
```